# PHP y JavaScript, radios para que aparzeca contenido de un div

Tags: php, javascript, web, webforms

estoy haciendo un formulario en index.php que tiene 3 radios(primer grupo), uno de los radios debe habilitar 2 radios más(segundo grupo), los radios del segundo grupo deben dar el estilo para que aparezcan los datos de un div, hasta ahí las funciones estan bien pero cuando selecciono otro radio del primer grupo no se desaparece los datos que mostró el segundo grupo, ¿me pueden ayudar con este problema?, de antemano gracias.
este es el archivo form.js

```js
    function show_options() { 
     insert = document.getElementById("show_insert");
     find = document.getElementById("show_buscar");
     modify = document.getElementById("show_modificar");
     radio_insert = document.getElementById("insert");
     radio_find = document.getElementById("find");
     radio_modify = document.getElementById("modify");
     if (radio_insert.checked) {
      insert.style.display='block';
      find.style.display='none';
      modify.style.display='none';
     }
     else{
      if (radio_find.checked) {
       insert.style.display='none';
       find.style.display='block';
       modify.style.display='none';
      }
      else{
       if (radio_modify.checked) {
        insert.style.display='none';
        find.style.display='none';
        modify.style.display='block';
       }
      }
     }
    };
    function show_ingres() {
     patient = document.getElementById("show_patient");
     deceased = document.getElementById("show_deceased");
     radio_deceased = document.getElementById("deceased");
     radio_infected = document.getElementById("patient");
     if (radio_infected.checked) {
      patient.style.display='block';
      deceased.style.display='none';  
     }
     else{
      if (radio_deceased.checked) {
       patient.style.display='none';
       deceased.style.display='block';  
      }
     }
    };
```

---

y este es el form.php

```html
    <div class="form">
     <form  class="needs-validation" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
       <label>
        <input type="radio" name="ibm" id="insert" value="ingresar" onchange="javascript:show_options()"> agregar
       </label>
       <label>
        <input type="radio" name="ibm" id="find" value="buscar" onchange="javascript:show_options()"> buscar
       </label>
       <label>
        <input type="radio" name="ibm" id="modify" value="modificar" onchange="javascript:show_options()"> mostrar
       </label>
       <div id="show_insert" style="display: none;">
        <label>
         <input type="radio" name="patient_deceased" id="patient" value="paciente" onchange="javascript:show_ingres()">paciente
        </label>
        <label>
         <input type="radio" name="patient_deceased" id="deceased" value="deceased" onchange="javascript:show_ingres()">fallecido
        </label>
       </div>
       <div id="show_patient" style="display: none;">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="ubicacion_paciente">ubicacion</label>
         <input id="ubicacion_paciente" class= "form-control" type="text" placeholder="ubicación"> 
        </div>
       </div>
       <div id="show_deceased" style="display: none; ">
        <label for="location_dead">direccion</label>
        <input id="location_dead" class= "form-control" type= "text" placeholder= "direccion"> 
       </div> 
     </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Agrega por favor tu código, te invito a leer [ask]

Comment: no puedo agregar el codigo me sale error

Comment: Agrega solo el código relevante a tu duda por favor así evitas que el sistema lo impida

Comment: ¿Así está bien?